# How to create a custom macro in laravel 4

Tags: php, macros, laravel, laravel-4

Good Day how can I use a custom macro in laravel 4?

here is my custom macro

```
<?php
HTML::macro('flash', function()
{
   $message_status = Session::get('status');
   $message        = Session::get('message');
   $type            = Session::get('type');

return ($message_status && $message) ? '<div class="alert alert-'.$message_status.'"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#" aria-hidden="true">&times;</a><p>'.$message.' '.$type.'</p></div>':'';

});
?>
```

I created a new file inside `app` folder named `macros.php` and paste the above code there, also added `require app_path().'/macros.php';` at the bottom of `app/start/global.php` , but when I try to access it on my view using `<?php echo HTML::flash(); ?>` I got this

```
syntax error, unexpected 'HTML' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)
```

also this is my way of passing values from my controller:

```
return Redirect::action('SuppliersController@show',$supplierId)
    ->with('status','success')
    ->with('message', Lang::get('alerts.messages.successUpdate'))
    ->with('type', Lang::get('alerts.transactions.po'));
```

Here is my view: [view](http://paste.laravel.com/1dxC)

[image: ERROR]

can anyone help me figure out whats going on here please. This is my first time on using custom macro.

Thank you very much

-Melvn

Comment: Looks like it should work, but I'm not sure about the include path. What happens if you just `echo HTML::flash();` right after defining the Macro on your view page?

Comment: thank you for your comment @TonyArra but even if I define the macro above the `echo HTML::flash()` Im still getting the same error, I think somethings wrong with `HTML::macro('flash', function()` part..

Comment: What you have works for me.. although you should note you're not putting those variables into the Session with `->with()`, that is just to pass the variables to the View.  So those values probably won't be accessible from the `Session::get()` .. that is not causing the error though!  :)

Comment: @melvnberd can you post some more of your view?  the part around the macro ?

Comment: @msturdy I added the a link for views above, please take a look.. Thank you very much!

Comment: looks ok!  can you post some more of the error message you get?

Comment: @msturdy already UPDATED my post.

Comment: You have pretty PHP parse errors? How did that happen?? The problem seems to be the previous line. PHP expects something else after the `}`. Open the compiled view and paste part of it.

Comment: Something seems bizarre here. Can you go to laravel/framework/Illuminate/Html/HtmlBuilder.php on your machine and see if your macro is somehow embedded in that code. I don't know if that picture is erroneous or if that's what's going on

Comment: where have you included that Macro, @melvnberd?  looks like it's been included into a module that you shouldn't even be touching.. did you put it in there?

Comment: @Rudie Thank you Rudie! finally found the code causing the error, it was when I added my macro at the bottom of the HtmlBuilder class, because I thought it should be added there. But after trying I forgot to remove it, and that caused the error.. I just didnt figured out imidiately due to the error message which says its on the 'HTML bla bla' Thank you very much for your assistance..! really helped! At the moment im still trying to figure out why my flash messages doesnt appearing! again Thank very much for that comment!

Comment: @melvnberd Two separate problems are always the best =) Can't help you with the Lavarel error.