# Share variable based on route group

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have 2 versions of a site. One is located in the root URL of the site and one is using a route prefix. They use the same resources but provide different links when accessed from the prefixed route:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    View::share('outgoing_url','something.com');
    //regular links here
});
```

and a few more of the above pointing to different routes or

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'tour'), function(){
    View::share('outgoing_url','somethingelse.com');
    //different links here 
});
```

View::share doesn't work since it uses whatever is assigned last so I am trying to find a solution for this problem.

Also, when I use HTML::link() in the views that go through the prefix, everything still points to the root URI of the site instead of the 'tour' prefix. Is there any way to differentiate between the two? Right now I am stuck with this problem and the only solution seems to be to make identical copies of the views and controllers responding to the routes. But that approach seems stupid to say the least.

I hope I explained the problem understandably.

Comment: Please expand: provide the snippets showing how you uses the alleged common resources within different disctinct controllers.

Comment: Same resources, same controllers and I want to ideally use the same views even. All I want to do is share a certain value in the grouped route and in the main routes.

Comment: BTW: Route prefixing applies only to a group of routes, so it has nothing to do with HTML::link().

Comment: Yes I already noticed that and that's the reason why I was asking if the HTML helper class can be modified to do what I need.

Comment: Yes, can write a custom Macro

Comment: How and where would I do that?

Comment: Head to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20529413/744588 - The answer is scattered in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a before filter - and set it that way

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    if (Request::segment(1) === 'tour')
    {
        View::share('outgoing_url','tour.com');
    }
    else
    {
        View::share('outgoing_url','other.com');
    }
});
```

Comment: I did something similar with a View::composer for the moment. It works out but doesn't address my HTML helper class problem, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

### HTML Macro:

```
<?php

    HTML::macro('myLink', function($url, $title = null, $attributes = array(), $secure = null)
    {
        if (Request::segment(1) === 'tour')
        {
            $url = 'tour/'.$url;
        }

        return HTML::link($url, $title, $attributes, $secure);
    });

?>
```

### Usage:

```
HTML::myLink(...);
```

Comment: It would be better to stick to the principle: `One post, one question`. Your post contains actually more than one question. This answer is only focused on how to write the Macro which would be ideally posted as a separate question.

Comment: To make it simple put the snippet at the end of `app/start/global.php`. Laravel's docs http://laravel.com/docs/lifecycle#start-files has more to tell.